# How to query for number of records in select with "group by" clause in JPA/EclipseLink?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

Suppose you have a following JPA query:

```
select car.year, car.month, count(car) from Car car group by car.year, car.month
```

Before we query for results, we need to know how many records this query will return (for pagination, UI and so on). In other words we need something like this:

```
select count(*) from 
    (select car.year, car.month, count(car) 
     from Car car group by car.year)
```

But JPA/EclipseLink does not support subqueries in "from" clause. It there a way around it?

(Of course you can use plain SQL and native queries, but this is not an option for us)

Comment: can't you just check size of the list of returned objects ? (I mean the first query returns resultList, it has a size - the value you actually need)

Comment: @john this only works if he doesn't use pagination

Comment: ok. what about JPA's native queries, I guess you can create a native query using any SQL (even with subqueries)

Comment: JPA doesn't have support for subqueries in the from clause, but EclipseLink does: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause

Answer (score 1):

A portable JPA solution:

```
select count(*) from Car c where c.id in
    (select MIN(car.id) from Car car group by car.year, car.month)
```

You could also go with something like:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(car.year, "#", car.month)) from car
```

but I expect this to be less performant due to operations with textual values.

Comment: Thanks. Considerable solution for some cases. Our queries are build on the fly and can have many fields with different data types, so it will be not easy (but possible) to build such a CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
select count(distinct car.year) from car
```

Comment: This sounds like a solution for queries with one field. What you suggest if we group by more than one field? "select car.year, car.month, count(car) from Car car group by car.year, car.month"

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach to solve this issue . by using my approach you don't need to know the no of rows this query is going to return.

here it is your solution :-

you going to need two variables

1) pageNo (your page no should be 1 for first request to data base and proceeding request it should be incremental like 2 ,3 , 4 5   ).

2) pageSize.

```
int start = 0;
        if(pageNo!=null && pageSize!=null){
            start = (pageNo-1) * pageSize;
        }else{

            pageSize = StaticVariable.MAX_PAGE_SIZE; // default page size if page no and page size are missing 
        }
```

your query

```
em.createquery("your query ")
.setfirstResult(start)
.setMaxResult(pageSize)
.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use setFirstResult and setMaxResult to set record bound for query ,also use size of list to return count of records that query runs. like this :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT d.name, COUNT(t) FROM Department d JOIN     
d.teachers t GROUP BY d.name");


//query.setFirstResult(5);
//query.setMaxResult(15); this will return 10 (from 5 to 15) record after query executed.
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
        Object[] arr = results.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
```

**-----Updated Section------**

JPA does not support sub-selects in the FROM clause but EclipseLink 2.4 current milestones builds does have this support.

See, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause

You can probably rewrite the query with just normal joins though.

Maybe,

```
Select a, size(a.bs) from A a
```

or

```
Select a, count(b) from A a join a.bs b group by a
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As @chris pointed out EclipseLink [supports subqueries](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Sub-selects_in_FROM_clause). But the subquery can't be the first one in the from-clause.

So I came up with the following workaround which is working:

```
select count(1) from Dual dual, 
    (select car.year, car.month, count(car) 
     from Car car group by car.year) data
```

1. `count(1)` is important as `count(data)` would not work
2. You have to add an entity Dual (If your database does not have a [DUAL table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table), create one with just one record.)

This works but I still consider it a workaround that would only work if you allowed to create the DUAL table.